# ip.address() does not work on aws. How to get the IP address of AWS EC2 programmatically?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, webpack

I developed a React application with Node/Express backend. It is based on the [following starter kit.](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) It works fine on my local machine but when I deploy it on AWS it starts with incorrect IP address.

My config file

```
    const ip = require('ip')
    server_host : ip.address(),
    server_port : process.env.PORT || 3000,
```

Running npm start on local machine - works fine and it starts as

```
    app:bin:server Server is now running at 192.168.1.5:3000.
```

but when I put it on EC2 (52.72.209.201) and start it doesn't work and I get the logs as

```
    app:bin:server Server is now running at 172.31.31.141:3000.
```

If I hardcode the IP address of my instance in the config file it works fine

```
    server_host : '52.72.209.201',
    server_port : process.env.PORT || 3000,
```

now it starts and runs fine

```
    app:bin:server Server is now running at 52.72.209.201:3000.
```

What can I do to remove hardcoded IP address?

Comment: did you attach any elastic IP? And hide your AWS EC2 instance IPs. Put some **.

Comment: Yes. Elastic IP is attached to the instance. I have not mentioned the exact IP address ;)

Comment: Did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861206/ip-address-does-not-work-on-aws-how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-aws-ec2-programm/40864195#40864195) help you? Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get your public IP address from:

- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4

or:

- http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4

You can use `curl` in a shell script (like your startup script) to get it and for example store in an environment variable or some file on the file system. Or you can use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) in Node.

For more info see:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 returns the same incorrect IP address = 172.31.31.141. Have I made any configuration mistakes while setting up the EC2 instance?